Polly 8 Resilience Library fallback issue
I am working with the Polly library for the first time trying to make my calls to a 3rd party SQL Server more robust. I've managed to successfully implement the retry and circuit breaker strategies. Now I am trying to use fallback and I am getting an error that I can't fix.
In my program.cs I declare the fallback policy as follows:
builder.Services.AddResiliencePipeline<string, DataTable?>("my-sql-pipeline", 
    pipelineBuilder =>
    {
        /*pipelineBuilder
            .AddRetry(retryDefault)
            .AddCircuitBreaker(cbDefaults);*/
        pipelineBuilder.AddFallback(new Polly.Fallback.FallbackStrategyOptions<DataTable?>
        {
            FallbackAction = _ => Outcome.FromResultAsValueTask(new DataTable())
        });
    });

The SQL returns a type of DataTable so, I want the fallback to return a blank DataTable.
In the method that implements the fallback I have:
public async Task<DataTable> RunSqlGetDt(string sql)
{
    var pipeline = _provider.GetPipeline<DataTable?>("my-sql-pipeline");

    var data = await pipeline.ExecuteAsync<DataTable?>(
        async token =>
        {
            await _client.RunSqlGetDt(sql);
        },
        CancellationToken.None);

    return data;
}

The code follows the example I have been following on YouTube, which compiles and works successfully yet the code above is giving me the following error:

CS1643    Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type 'Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask<DataTable?>>'

I can't see the path that is not returning a value in the Lamda function. Can someone please save my sanity?

Either use async token => { return await _client.RunSqlGetDt(sql); } or async token => await _client.RunSqlGetDt(sql)

The fix was to add return as in Peter's comment.
public async Task<DataTable> RunSqlGetDt(string sql)
{
    var pipeline = _provider.GetPipeline<DataTable?>("my-sql-pipeline");

    var data = await pipeline.ExecuteAsync<DataTable?>(
    async token =>
    {
        return await _client.RunSqlGetDt(sql);
    },
    CancellationToken.None);

    return data;
}

